# Setting width to all divs

Tags: html, width, stylesheet

I'm sure it's very simple, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to alter the width of the divs.

I need them to be at 1024px, I have it set in the style sheet for each one, and it ***still*** refuses to do it.  Can someone *please* point out what I'm missing?

Comment: could you please paste the code , how you are setting the width to divs

Comment: So block elements have width now, interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hard to answer your question without seeing the code but since you mention scripting and maybe you are using jquery this should do it

```
 $('div').css("width","1024px");
```